# Alternative terminal for Ubuntu that supports predefined sessions

Tags: command-line

I am looking for a better (GUI) terminal for Ubuntu that supports:

- tabs, preferably colored ones
- change notification - output is changed on an inactive terminal
- define a list of servers to connect to

The default terminal app does supports tabs but not the things above.

Answer (score 2):

After looking around for a bit, the closest application to meet all your requirements would be [terminator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee) [image: Install terminator]

- It doesn't have tabs *but* you can split the windows any way you want to.
- It does have options to customize colors and other things the way you want.
- It also has a notification plugin that you can setup to use to watch for inactivity or activity, depending on your need. There's a question here, [What do the ActivityWatch and InactivityWatch plugins do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119977/what-do-the-activitywatch-and-inactivitywatch-plugins-do), that you can use to understand this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [Guake](http://guake.org/) a try. It's full of features.
Available from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Sorry, not meeting requirements, by far.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer byobu with tmux and gnome-terminal.

You can set your profiles in gnome-terminal to start any command you like as a shell. So you could even create different profiles and set the custom command as byobu or tmux with different config files.