# What do the ActivityWatch and InactivityWatch plugins do?

Tags: command-line, terminator

I have search on google but I don't have found anything about the meas of this two plugins: Inactivity watch and Activity watch.

Anyone can explain me how it works?
I have tried to activate/deactivate it but I can't see anything.

[image: Plugins tab]

Comment: in 11.10 I've installed terminator - there was no "inactivitywatch" - but there was an "activitywatch" - where did you get "inactivitywatch" ?

Comment: is a default plugin of 0.96-0ubuntu1 package (universe precise repository)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### InactivityWatch

This new plugin was developed as described in this [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/343616).

> "Watch for silence" is useful in the following scenario: Suppose you
> have a long-running job that produces output while it is running, for
> example building some software. Then it would be cool to select the
> "Watch for silence" action. This would continuously monitor activity
> in the terminal, and when no output arrives for some configurable
> time, it would mark the window as urgent so that it flashes in the
> Gnome taskbar.
>
> "Watch for activity" complements "watch for silence" and is useful for
> long-running jobs that seldom produce output, and you want to be
> alerted when output happens. Perhaps "tail -F /some/log/file | grep
> SomePattern" is a typical example.

Looking at the plugins source-code (`/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/plugins/activitywatch.py`), it is actually not configurable - it is hard-coded to display a notification 10 seconds after a file was last updated.  Once this notification has been displayed, no further notifications are shown until the next file update.

[image]

### ActivityWatch

When monitoring a log file, it is sometimes useful to be prompted when it has been updated.

[image]

A notification is sent whenever the file has been updated.

N.B. once a notification is displayed, another notification is not sent for another hard-coded 10 seconds, thus you dont have a continual stream of notifications being displayed for a continually updated file.

### How to enable

Perhaps slightly confusing, the *inactivitywatch* and *activitywatch* plugins are displayed not by their plugin names.

Right-click a terminator pane - you can individually set to either *watch for silence* or *watch for activity* or both.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the InactivityWatch plugin, but I can tell you what the ActivityWatch plugin does:

Right click a terminal window you're in and click "Watch for activity".
Now, any time there is activity in that terminal, a notification through pynotify will be sent (which calls libnotify) and should show a notification on your desktop.

I am going to assume that the InactivityWatch plugin does the opposite of the ActivityWatch plugin and alerts you of a (long) inactivity in that terminal window.

Comment: That's correct. Actually, both plugins are defined in `/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/plugins/activitywatch.py`.